# SQL - can the rows and columns be easily transposed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

I have the table below setup from a query where I'm summing at each column

```
201501 | 201502 | 201503 | 201504 | ... | 201512

xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx | ... | xxxxx
```

What I need is this table to transpose to this:

```
       | Amount |
201501   xxxxxx
201502   xxxxxx
201503   xxxxxx
...
201512   xxxxxx
```

Is there an easy way to approach this? Any help is appreciated, I can post the query as well if that is helpful, thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a pivot table problem. What data base engine are you using?

Comment: Specifically, `UNPIVOT`, but it's not really possible to say more without knowing which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Then you are looking for [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unpivot` to do this transpose. Add other columns as needed.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/990331/4)

```
select datecolumn, amount from
(select * from tablename) t
unpivot
(amount for datecolumn in ([201501],[201502],[201503],[201504],[201505],[201506])) u
```